# How to copy items to existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new in PHP. I have reviewed some other threads about the array combination but I couldn't found the answer.

For example the first array

```
array (
  'date' => '01.06.2019',
  'day' => 'Saturday',
)
```

Second array

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 10,
    'name' => 'Mj phooi',
  ),
)
```

Expected result

```
array (
  'date' => '01.06.2019',
  'day' => 'Saturday',
  'id' => 10,
  'name' => 'Mj phooi',
)
```

I did try the `array_combine` and `array_merge_recursive` but it doesn't work. The closure result I tried is like `$result = array_merge($arr,$temp);`. It combined two arrays but there have two arrays inside which not match with the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, you could use [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) but the array in the $temp is a nested array so you might take the first index `0`:

```
$arr = [
    'date' => '01.06.2019',
    'day' => 'Saturday',
];

$temp = [
    [
        'id' => 10,
        'name' => 'Mj phooi',
    ]
];


print_r(array_merge($arr, $temp[0]));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [date] => 01.06.2019
    [day] => Saturday
    [id] => 10
    [name] => Mj phooi
)
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/A5Ir0)

Note that an array can not have duplicate keys so if they have the same keys the last will override the existing key.